# Tire search and will_paginate - undefined method `offset'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, elasticsearch

After headaches with ThinkingSphinx and Solr/Sunspot, we're trying out ElasticSearch and Tire as our search back-end - but I've hit a problem.

Here's my search command in the controller:

```
@results = Item.search params[:search], :page => ( params[:page] || 1 ), :per_page => 20
```

And this is the problem section of the view:

```
<%= page_entries_info @results %>
```

The error message I'm getting is

```
undefined method `offset' for #<Tire::Results::Collection:0xa3f01b0>
```

but only when there is more than one page's worth of results. If there are less than 20 items returned, then they get shown fine.

The only similar reported issue I could find elsewhere was solved by passing the `:page` and `:per_page` parameters into the `search` function, but I'm already doing that, to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tire has [a Pagination module](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/results/pagination.rb) but it doesn't define `offset`. You could file an issue with them to add it, but in the meantime you can monkeypatch it in your app:

```
Tire::Results::Pagination.module_eval do
  def offset
    (@options[:per_page] || @options[:size] || 10 ).to_i * (current_page - 1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @mislav, maybe something like a "lint" test for will_paginate compatible collections would be nice? Something along the lines of ActiveModel::Lint?

Comment: As it turns out, it also needed a length method, but I was able to patch that in as well. Thanks! :)

Comment: @karmi: yeah a lint test would be nice. You can always contribute it unless I get to it sooner! ;)

Comment: @PaulC: Which version you're on? `length` was added long time ago: <https://github.com/karmi/tire/commit/d4db448>

Comment: @mislav: In the end, I've picked it up from this spec: <https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/spec/collection_spec.rb#L36> Probably just put this as unit tests + specs into a `Lint::Tests` and `Lint::Specs` modules and it's done...

Answer (score 1):

in my testapp, results are paginated just fine, with `will_paginate 3.0` and `tire 0.3`. I wasn't aware will_paginate *needed* the `offset` method.

I've added it, however, copying over the "lint" test from `will_paginate` specs: https://github.com/karmi/tire/commit/e0e7730. Should be part of the next release.