# Tire not working with will_paginate in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I'm currently searching two models (Posts and Channels), using Tire and ElasticSearch.

I need to add pagination using will_paginate. The issue is, Tire doesn't appear to support will_paginate in the controller (:page and :per_page don't work...). It turns out, to use pagination with Tire, you have to call it in your model.

The problem with calling Tire in my models is, if I do this, Tire won't let me search my two models (Posts and Channels) at the same time.

So... long story short... if I use Tire in the controller, I can't have pagination but I can search my two models at the same time. If I use Tire in my models, I can't search both of my models at the same time, but I can have pagination.

This just seems dumb. Is there a way around this?

For reference, here's the code from my controller that allows me to search both of my models at the same time:

```
def browse
    @user = current_user
    @search_items = Tire.search(['posts_index', 'channels_index'], load: true) do |search|
      if params[:query].present? 
        search.query do |q|
          q.string params[:query], default_operator: "AND"
        end
      end
      search.filter :term, :visibility => ['public']
      search.sort { by :created_at, "desc" }
    end
    @results = @search_items.results
end
```

Comment: this link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306623/tire-search-and-will-paginate-undefined-method-offset